# Can I get timedelta(days=180) from datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d') in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a script that moves files whose names begin with YYYYMMDD (example 20180201, 20180203) to an archive directory if they are older than 180 days. This script will run every day from a cron job.

So **datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')** returns a string, obviously. I can't seem to find a way to have datetime return in an int.

I could do this:
toDay = int(datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d'))
but somehow that seems kludgey.

I can't figure out what kind of object datetime.timedelta(days=180) produces.

Comment: Turning *today* into a string is of no use to you.  You want to turn the filename into a date (`datetime.strptime()`), and subtract that from today to see how old it is.

Comment: I know how old the filenames are. They are named for the YYMMDD they were created. The files already exist. I'm not trying to create files. I'm trying to find the ones that are more than 180 days old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It produces a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object.  You can add and subtract `timedelta` objects with objects like `datetime` objects to produce new objects with the time changed by that amount.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_date_from_filename(filename):
    return datetime.strptime(filename[:8], "%Y%m%d")

filename = "20180201file.txt"
today= datetime.today()

if get_date_from_filename(filename) + timedelta(days=180) <= today:
    print("File is 180 days old")
else:
    print("file is not that old")
```

Comment: @mr.zog I had a typo in the function name, was that what you were referring to?

Comment: Even with the today= typo fixed I can't get it to run as a script. I was once able to run it in ipython3. Guess there's something wrong with my env. 
Losing my mind learning Python :)

Comment: @mr.zog It might not have liked the `if` with only a comment.

Comment: Your edited version works fine now, even with the typo ;)
Now I'm wondering whether my vim config is messing with whitespace.